# Proving properties about matrix $A$ s.t. $A^2 = -I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is $nxn$ matrix, and $A^2=-I$. Show $A$ is non-singular and show that $n$ is even.

(Further questions, show that $A$ has no real eigenvalues. Show det(A) = 1. But I'm not there yet.)

So if $A$ is nonsingular then det(A) $\neq$ 0. But I can't figure out how to show the det(A) is not zero.

Comment: Have you tried to apply $\text{det}$ to both sides of the equation $A^2=-I$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take the determinant in both sides of $A^2 = -I$ to see that $A$ is invertible.
2. If $n$ is odd what is the determinant of $-I$? Use the fact that $\det(A^2) = (\det(A))^2$.
3. You know that $A^2+I = 0$. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $Av = \lambda v$ for some $v$ and $A^2v=  \lambda^2 v$. Use the fact that $A^2 = -I$ to find an equation for $\lambda$. What are the possible solutions? Are they real?
4. The determinant of $A$ is the product of its eigenvalues. From 2. you have $\det(A) \in \{-1,1\}$. Since the eigenvalues of $A$ can be only $i$ or $-i$ (hope you found this in 3.), and their sum is a real number (the trace of $A$), you must have the same number of $i$ and of $-i$. Thus their product is $i^{n/2}(-i)^{n/2} = 1$.

Comment: Not really getting how to derive $\lambda = i$ or $\lambda = -i$.

Comment: How do you know that their sum is a real number?

Comment: The equation you get for $\lambda$ is $\lambda^2 = -1$. This has roots $\pm i$. The sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace (the sum of the elements on the diagonal), and since $A$ has real entries, the trace is real.

Answer (score 1):

suppose $$Ax = b \to A^2x=Ab \to x = -Ab $$  therefore, $A$ is invertible and $$A^{-1} = -A.  $$

Answer (score 0):

$$det(A^2) = det(A)^2 = det(-I) = (-1)^n$$

Since $\det(A)^2$ is positive, we have $n$ even and $\det(A)^2 = 1$ hence it can't be $0$

This should help also for the other questions

Answer (score 0):

Without determinants:

$$A^2=-I\implies -A^2=A(-A)=I\implies -A=A^{-1}$$